# Appended DIV showing up only on resize

Tags: jquery, html, json

For my portfolio site I am calling a json object, parsing it and dynamically building the div. All are working fine but my appended div is not showing up. It is blank. If I try to resize my window, the contents are magically appearing.

Site is http://imajination.in

Js is -> root-> JS -> Main.js ( line 65 )

```
$.getJSON('./clients.txt',function(data){
     for(var i in data) {
          var generated = '
          <div id="siteRoll">
               <div class="thumb"><img src="clients/'+data[i].thumb+'"></div>
               <div class="info">
                    <span class="title">'+data[i].name+'</span>
                    <span class="desc">CLIENT : '+data[i].client+'</span>
                    <span class="desc">TYPE   : '+data[i].type+'</span>
                    <span class="desc2">'+data[i].desc1+'</span>
                    <span class="desc2">'+data[i].desc2+'</span>
                    <span class="visit"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank">Visit site</a></span>
               </div><!-- info -->
          </div><!-- siteRoll -->';

          $('article#portfolio #sliderPort .swipe-wrap').append(generated);
     }
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I've got a performance fix idea - don't append this row by row, build up the generated variable in full and only then append that onto the page - could possibly save a lot of unnecessary processing

Comment: also, no need to use multiple id selectors (#), as IDs are unique to page, so `$('#sliderPort .swipe-wrap')` will work fine on its own (and will be much quicker, as jQuery don't need to go through all articles to find what you're looking for) ;)

Comment: Your `.swipe-wrap` has `width: 0px` set when the page renders for the first time. That's what causing the invisibility problem. Maybe you should start there.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Thanks!! I am gonna append them finally and change the ID. Width:0px is something the plugin does. I dont think its an issue.. Let me look at it too!

Comment: besides the other comments, you are generating duplicate ids with that code. the `id="siteRoll"` is inside the loop so each iteration creates a new div with that id..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli nice catch, didn't see it there :)

Comment: The Div is not an issue though. The plugin i am using is getting activated before the generation. I changed the flow and it worked.. Thanks for tat, i am gonna change it to class !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
$.getJSON('./clients.txt',function(data) {
 var htm = null;
 for(var i in data) {
      htm += '
      <div id="siteRoll">
           <div class="thumb"><img src="clients/'+data[i].thumb+'"></div>
           <div class="info">
                <span class="title">'+data[i].name+'</span>
                <span class="desc">CLIENT : '+data[i].client+'</span>
                <span class="desc">TYPE   : '+data[i].type+'</span>
                <span class="desc2">'+data[i].desc1+'</span>
                <span class="desc2">'+data[i].desc2+'</span>
                <span class="visit"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank">Visit    site</a></span>
           </div><!-- info -->
      </div><!-- siteRoll -->';
  }

  $('article#portfolio #sliderPort .swipe-wrap').html(htm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be building your carousel on page load, but appending its content just after the page loads. Most carousels (assuming it's a plugin) don't work that way - you need to have your content present before you build up the content.

This particular carousel seem to react on window.resize as well, so that's the reason why you get contents only once you resize window and the carousel refreshes.

I'd look at a refresh() method, if the plugin supports it and call it once you append the dynamic data on page load.